# How to use the loop with $index

Tags: angularjs

When I use the code above in html I can't get the result that I want because I have problem in:

```
<my-grid options="{{'all.Options'+$index}}"  class="grid"></my-grid>
```

because I want to show data of `all.Options0` and 1 by looping

```js
 all.Options0 = {
            data: all.myData,
        };
        
all.Options1 = {
            data: all.myDataTwo,
          
        };
```

```html
<div ng-repeat="n in [].constructor(2) track by $index">
      {{$index}}  <br>
      <my-grid options="{{'all.Options'+$index}}"  class="grid"></my-grid>
      <br> <br> <br> <br>
    </div>
```

Comment: You do not need that `track by $index` part, `$index` will be available automatically.

Comment: Could you try check my answer and let me know?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure your  `ng-repeat="n in [].constructor(2) track by $index"` working well or not. If your `ng-repeat` code works properly. then try **`options="{{all['Options'+$index]}}"`** instead of `options="{{'all.Options'+$index}}"` because you should provide correct object instead of string `'all.Options'`.

So the correct way is

```
options="{{all['Options'+$index]}}"
```

Comment: yeah the ng-repeat is working well but this solution has an error in syntax

Comment: Error: [$parse:syntax]

Comment: @developer try this `options="{{all['Options'+$index]}}"`.  I have updated it in my answer.